# Multiple values of same JSON Tag

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have one JSON Object coming to HTML which I am transferring to javascript function which are all defined below. Problem is I am getting same folderName listed in repition on HTML page.

JSON Object:

```
{
    "folderName": "arjunram-test",
    "objects": [
        {
            "keyName": "ShadowBalanceMismatch_April.csv",
            "keyValue": "ShadowBalanceMismatch_April.csv"
        },
        {
            "keyName": "rawLogs.txt",
            "keyValue": "rawLogs.txt"
        },
        {
            "keyName": "expiredpoints.txt",
            "keyValue": "expiredpoints.txt"
        }
    ],
    "childDirs": [
        {
            "folderName": "20140601.csv",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "keyName": "expiredpoints.txt",
                    "keyValue": "20140601.csv/expiredpoints.txt"
                }
            ],
            "childDirs": [
                {
                    "folderName": "20140601-test",
                    "objects": [
                        {
                            "keyName": "CustomerID.txt",
                            "keyValue": "20140601.csv/20140601-test/CustomerID.txt"
                        }
                    ],
                    "childDirs": []
                },
                {
                    "folderName": "test-folder",
                    "objects": [
                        {
                            "keyName": "Amazon_Points_proposal20110421_final.docx",
                            "keyValue": "20140601.csv/test-folder/Amazon_Points_proposal20110421_final.docx"
                        }
                    ],
                    "childDirs": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "folderName": "20140602.csv",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "keyName": "[Songs.PK] 01 - Ek Villain - Galliyan.mp3",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/[Songs.PK] 01 - Ek Villain - Galliyan.mp3"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "screen1.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/screen1.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "[Songs.PK] 05 - Ek Villain - Hamdard.mp3",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/[Songs.PK] 05 - Ek Villain - Hamdard.mp3"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "[Songs.PK] 06 - Ek Villain - Galliyan (Unplugged).mp3",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/[Songs.PK] 06 - Ek Villain - Galliyan (Unplugged).mp3"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "[Songs.PK] 04 - Ek Villain - Awari.mp3",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/[Songs.PK] 04 - Ek Villain - Awari.mp3"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "2.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/2.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-2.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-2.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "3.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/3.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "0.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/0.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "Form 2 Guide.pdf",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/Form 2 Guide.pdf"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "screen3.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/screen3.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-0-3.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-0-3.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-1-3.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-1-3.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-1-1.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-1-1.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "[Songs.PK] 02 - Ek Villain - Banjaara.mp3",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/[Songs.PK] 02 - Ek Villain - Banjaara.mp3"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-1.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-1.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-0-2.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-0-2.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-0-1.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-0-1.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "1.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/1.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "screen2.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/screen2.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "base.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/base.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "[Songs.PK] 03 - Ek Villain - Zaroorat.mp3",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/[Songs.PK] 03 - Ek Villain - Zaroorat.mp3"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-pending.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-pending.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-3.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-3.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "All.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/All.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "screen4.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/screen4.JPG"
                },
                {
                    "keyName": "4-1-2.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "20140602.csv/4-1-2.JPG"
                }
            ],
            "childDirs": [
                {
                    "folderName": "testing-paging",
                    "objects": [
                        {
                            "keyName": "0.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/0.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-pending.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-pending.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-1.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-1.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-3.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-3.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-0-3.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-0-3.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-0-2.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-0-2.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-0-1.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-0-1.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "1.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/1.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-1-3.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-1-3.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-1-1.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-1-1.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "2.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/2.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-2.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-2.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "3.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/3.JPG"
                        },
                        {
                            "keyName": "4-1-2.JPG",
                            "keyValue": "20140602.csv/testing-paging/4-1-2.JPG"
                        }
                    ],
                    "childDirs": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "folderName": "test-repet",
            "objects": [
                {
                    "keyName": "4-pending.JPG",
                    "keyValue": "test-repet/4-pending.JPG"
                }
            ],
            "childDirs": []
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel accordion clearfix" id="dispdir">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            showDirectorySegment(${S3DirectoryList},"folder",null);  <!-- ${S3DirectoryList} contains JSON Object as defined above
        };
    </script>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showFolders( folderList ) {

    console.log(folderList.length);
    var markup = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++ ) {
         var fid = "folder_"+folderId;
         markup += "<div class=\"well clearfix\" style=\"background-color:#FFE88D;font-size:15px\">";
         markup += "<a style=\"text-decoration:none\" id='" + fid + "'><i class=\"fa fa-folder\"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;" + folderList[i].folderName + "</a></div>";
         $("#dispdir").append(markup);   
         $("#" + fid).on("click",
                    (function(i){
                        return function(){
                            showDirectorySegment(folderList[i],"folder", fid);
                        };
                    })(i)
                );
         folderId += 1;
    }
}

function showDirectorySegment( dirList, target, elemId ) {

    var markup = "";
    var pid;

    markup += "<div class=\"clearfix\">";
    markup += showObjects(dirList.objects) + "<br><br>";
    document.getElementById("dispdir").innerHTML = markup;
    showFolders(dirList.childDirs);
    $("#dispdir").append("</div>");

    if ( target == "folder" ) {
        pid = "path_" + pathId;
        var pMarkup = "<a  style=\"text-decoration:none\" id='" + pid + "'>" + dirList.folderName + "&nbsp;/</a>";
        $("#dirpath").append( pMarkup );
        $("#" + pid).on("click",function(){
                        showDirectorySegment(dirList, "path", pid);
                    });
        pathId += 1;
    } else if ( target == "path" ) {
        $("#"+elemId).nextAll().remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the silly mistake that every programmer is bound to do and has a right to it. 
There was just a need to remove '+' sign from first markup statement inside the loop in getFolders function